# Html sum of check box

Tags: javascript, html

This is my html code

```
<tr>
        <td style="width: 200px" >&nbsp;&nbsp;<label> Subject</label>&nbsp;</td>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <td colspan="1"><input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Bahasa Malaysia
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <td colspan="1"><input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox">Bahasa Inggeris</td>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <td colspan="1"><input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Bahasa Cina</td>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <td colspan="1"><input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Mathematic</td>
        </label>
        <label class="checkbox">
        <td colspan="1"><input value="50" type="checkbox" class="sum" data-toggle="checkbox"> Math Tambahan</td>
        </label>
    </tr>
```

This is my javascript

```
   var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
    total  = document.getElementById('fees');

  for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].onchange = function() {
        var add = this.value * (this.checked ? 1 : -1);
        total.value = parseFloat(total.value) + add
    }
}
```

The problem i facing now is ,the value cannot come out in the textfield while i tick the checkbox ,each checkbox value is 50 ,when i tick it ,it will appear in the textbox and sum all.but the value i get now is Nan. Please help me this up .Thank you

Comment: Can't you use jQuery?

Comment: because i dint learn jQuery, so i no idea how to write it out, but can you please help me code it?

Comment: I keep get the Nan value

Comment: you can check if value is nan by calling the function `isNan(number)` and if it is, you can assign `0` to it

Comment: i no idea to wrote this, please help me ,i m beginner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkbox value is technically a string and not a number. You need to convert it to a number:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
     total = document.getElementById('fees');

 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
     inputs[i].onchange = function () {
         /* Use parseInt(this.value) otherwise it is a String */
         var add = parseInt(this.value) * (this.checked ? 1 : -1); 
         total.value = parseFloat(total.value) + add
     }
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8c9ntfcu/

Comment: But the text field still appear NaN

Comment: what is this? you just copied and added console statement. even don't say a word

Comment: you need to parseInt(this.value);

Answer (score 0):

Add `onChange="add()"` to each of your inputs.

Then use the following javascript..

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('sum'),
var total = document.getElementById('fees');

var add = function () {
    var amount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
       if (inputs[i].checked === true) {
            amount += parseInt(inputs[i].value, 10);
        }
    }
    console.log(amount);
};
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adamjld/0xbzw034/)